# IBM cloud-private-2.1.0.3 502 gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

in IBM cloud-private after installation success, when I run the IBM-cloud-private URL like **192.168.*.***:8443** I'm getting 502 gateway error. Can you, please, suggest me how to address this issue?

Comment: Your description is very brief about your problem. Please elaborate and provide images to support it.

Comment: I would suggest adding the pod logs from the platform-ui pod and auth-idp's platform-auth container as well to help flesh out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Often, IBM Cloud Private (ICP) will install successfully even though the cluster environment is under the minimum system requirements. Then the cluster experiences issues such as 502 gateway during runtime. Please ensure your cluster environment meets these minimum hardware requirements outlined here in the ICP Knowledge Center (KC): https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0.3/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html

ICP Support Portal: http://ibm.biz/icpsupport